# Copy 1 or multiple column structures from a table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

```
            ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN LIKE c1,c2 FROM t2
```

The above query does not work when I try, is there a way to accomplish this where I can copy, NOT the data but just specific columns with their structures to another already existing table

Comment: Only create table supports the like option, alter table does not. I'm not aware of any solution apart ftom creating a new table from the two old tables

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I think ALTER TABLE does not support LIKE option